# Cucumber tests execution stops only when running using Surefire plugin in parrallel

Tags: java, maven, concurrency, maven-surefire-plugin

I am having troubles when ruuning cucumber tests in parrallel with surefire plugin.

I have three steps classes, they extend Abstract class but the execution does even not reach the constructor of the parent class, so I assume something is wrong my setup/build configuration. 
Something has to be wrong with the parrallel execution but I am not sure what it might be. If someone can help I can provide more information about the code/config.

When I run the RegressionTests.runner without the parallel execution everything is ok.
But when I run them using following maven command, execution hangs right after "TESTS" log is printed out and I have to kill the process.

```
My maven command:

    surefire:test -Dtest=RegressionTests
```

[image: Stopped execution]
[image: ThreadDump]
[image: log1]
[image]

pom.xlm file

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
     <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>both</parallel>
          <threadCount>4</threadCount>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${sonar.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Runner class

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/ratings/",
    plugin = "json:target/cucumber-report.json",
    monochrome = true,
    tags = "@regression")
public class RegressionTests {
}
```

Comment: Your configuration looks correct. You should replace `4.2.0` with `${cucumber.version}` though. 

You are using a milestone release for surefire. Could you downgrade surefire to `2.22.1`? 

Setting a break point won't help. Surefire spawns a new jvm to run the tests in parallel in. You can set https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkCount to zero to work around that.

I'm afraid this is https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve territory though. Can you create one using github?